# Programmaticaly opening new windows and updating them periodically

Tags: c#, wpf, window, visual-studio-2017

Working on a aplication, that is gonna monitor some files and on file change, show that change in new window for each file.

Once user selects which file to monitor, a new window should open on button click. In the background I trigger `FileSystemWatcher` to watch this file for changes. Once change happens, I have to update this newly opened window (with textbox) with some information.

I have already set up new Window1 (Project -> Add Window -> Window (WPF)).
The rest of the code looks like this:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = current_log.FullName.Substring(0, current_log.FullName.LastIndexOf('\\'));

watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
           | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

watcher.Filter = current_log.Name;
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

//check if window is already active
//????

//open new window
Window1 log_window = new Window1();
log_window.Show();
log_window.txt_log_window_messages.AppendText("ddd\n");
```

Questions:

- How to check if this file already has a monitor window active, to not open it again?
- How to identify in which window I should update textbox in `OnChanged()` function?

Comment: You could have a dictionary

Comment: Use Hashtable \ Dictionary with FileName as Key, and Window instance as Value.

Comment: I love simple solutions, thank you both!

Comment: Like BugFinder writes you could maintain a Dictionary<string, Window> where you simply check if a user has the file open (i.e. the Dictionary .ContainsKey is true for the filepath). That will simultaneously give you a reference to the window to update.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccomend to work with a `Dictionary` here. Something like this:

```
ictionary<string, Window1> files = new Dictionary<string, Window1>();

private void init()
{
    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
    watcher.Path = current_log.FullName.Substring(0, current_log.FullName.LastIndexOf('\\'));

    watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
       | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

    watcher.Filter = current_log.Name;
    watcher.Changed += Watcher_Changed;
    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void Watcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    if(!files.ContainsKey(e.Name))
    {
        //open new window
        Window1 log_window_new = new Window1();            

        files.Add(e.Name, log_window_new);
        log_window_new.Show();
        log_window_new.txt_log_window_messages.AppendText("ddd\n");
    }

    // Update existing window
    Window1 log_window= files[e.Name];
    log_window.txt_log_window_messages.AppendText("tttt\n");
}
```